# C26486 with string_view

Tags: c++, string, c++17

Compilling the code below in MSVS with c++ core guidlines enabled produces warning:

`C26486 LIFETIMES_FUNCTION_PRECONDITION_VIOLATION` - [Link to relevant Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26486?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C26486)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019)

```
using vec_pair = std::vector<std::pair<const std::string_view, const std::string_view>>;

void foo(const vec_pair& vec_pair) noexcept
{
    for (auto [first, second] : vec_pair) //<---- Warning here
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

int main()
{
    const vec_pair my_vec_pair { {
        {"yes", "no"},
        {"what", "why"},
        {"salt", "pepper"},
    } };

    foo(my_vec_pair);

    return 0;
}
```

Description is:

```
Don't pass a pointer that may be invalid to a function. Parameter 0 '$S1' in call to '<move><std::pair<std::basic_string_view<char,std::char_traits<char> > const ,std::basic_string_view<char,std::char_traits<char> > const > & __ptr64>' may be invalid (lifetime.3).
```

Changing std::string_view to std::string does not help. Nor does checking for nullptr both before and after the for loop.

How should I deal with this?

Comment: File a bug report with MSVC.

Comment: Ah, wasnt aware if it was a bug or me making a mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the Core Guidelines checker. The bug is actually in its understanding of structured bindings to tuple-like types (such as `std::pair`); a minimal example is:

```
#include <utility>
void foo(std::pair<int, int> p) noexcept {
    auto const [x, y] = p;
}
```

It appears that the checker is being confused by the treatment of the invented variable as an xvalue; see **Case 2: binding a tuple-like type** at [Structured binding declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) and [**dcl.struct.bind**](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind#4). A workaround is to use a *ref-qualifier* of `&` so that the invented variable is treated as an lvalue:

```
#include <utility>
void foo(std::pair<int, int> p) noexcept {
    auto const& [x, y] = p;
    //        ^
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/FcwUD9).

Note: admittedly, that workaround won't work in this case, since it falls foul of *C26445: A reference to gsl::span or std::string_view may be an indication of a lifetime issue (gsl.view).* If you can't suppress or ignore the warning, you'll have to use `first` and `second` like in the old days.